# Vue $emit and @click handler behaving differently on Firefox

Tags: vue.js, firefox, vue-component, vue-router, eventemitter

New to Vue and wrapping my head around the main concepts.

I currently have two separate components `BodyHero.vue` and `SelectedHero.vue` that I need to pass data from `BodyHero.vue` to `SelectedHero.vue`. Since there isn't a parent-child relationship between them I've set up a simple EventBus.

```
import Vue from 'vue'
export const EventBus = new Vue()
```

I've set up a simple emitter to pass information from `BodyHero.vue` to `SelectedHero.vue`upon click on `router-link`. (I'm using vue-router to route pages and the routes work appropriately - upon click the user is taken from `BodyHero.vue` to `SelectedHero.vue`.)

This is a portion of `BodyHero.vue`:

```
<template>
 <div class="columns" style="margin: 0px 10px">
  <div v-for="cryptoCurrency in firstFiveCryptoCurrencies" class="column">
    <router-link to="/selected" @click.native="selectCryptoCurrency(cryptoCurrency)">
      <div class="card">
        <div class="card-image">
          <figure class="image is-4by3">
            <img :src="`/static/${cryptoCurrency.id}_logo.png`">
          </figure>
        </div>
        <div class="card-content">
          <p class="title is-5">{{ cryptoCurrency.name }}</p>
        </div>
      </div>
    </router-link>
  </div>
 </div>
</template>

<script>
import { EventBus } from '../../event-bus.js'
const cryptoCurrencyData = require('../../cryptocurrency-data.json')

export default {
 props: {},
 name: 'bodyHero',
 selectCryptoCurrency (cryptoCurrency) {
  EventBus.$emit('cryptoCurrencySelected', cryptoCurrency)
}
```

And in `SelectedHero.vue`, upon `created` I listen for the emit.

```
 created () {
  EventBus.$on('cryptoCurrencySelected', cryptoCurrency => {
   ...
  })
 }
```

Now for the weird part. Chrome/Safari everything seems to work fine - the user is routed to the next component, the emit is successfully called and the `cryptoCurrency` object is appropriately passed.

For Firefox however, it appears that the `EventBus.$emit('cryptoCurrencySelected', cryptoCurrency)` doesn't seem to fire upon click (`@click.native`). So the user is directed to the next screen - and the object is empty. Not sure what's really the issue here or if I'm missing something. Would be happy to hear other opinions!

Comment: Shot in the dark but if you remove the camel casing from the event does it work? `cryptoCurrencySelected` to `cryptocurrencyselected`?

Comment: @BertEvans. Unfortunately still doesn't work.
 
On a separate note, I noticed console.log statements within the method work fine (in FireFox). So the method is being hit - but its sort of just skipping over `EventBus.$emit('cryptoCurrencySelected', cryptoCurrency)`

Comment: `click.native.prevent`?

Comment: @RoyJ, `@click.native.prevent` doesn't make it work either. Not 100% sure what that does but will go through the docs now.

Comment: What about just `@click`?